# UIPickerView calls viewForRowInComponent

Tags: ios, uipickerview

It seems my UIPickerView calls for viewForRowInComponent even if I declare that i have 0 rows in my pickerview. Why is that ?

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  return self.showingBanks ? self.banks.count : self.bankBranches.count;
}
```

and for this case matter both banks and bankBranches are **empty** initialized NSMutableArrays

Comment: What do you mean "if I declare that i have 0 rows in my pickerview".

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDataSource/pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:):

> Called by the picker view when it needs the number of rows for a specified component. (required)

UIPickerView will call the operation `pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:` every time when it has to show/repaint the content.

**UIPickerView**

Since there is no operation called **viewForRowInComponent** i guess you mean `viewForRow:forComponent:`.

From [UIPickerView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/viewForRow:forComponent:):

> **Return Value**
>
> The view provided by the delegate in the
>   **pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:** method. Returns nil if
>   the specified row of the component is not visible or if the delegate
>   does not implement pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:.

**UIPickerViewDelegate**

Perhaps you mean the delegate method `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`? 
In my project this method will never called as long as the data source method `pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:` returns 0

Comment: please reread the question, it does not ask why "numberofRowsInComponent" is called, but rather why "viewForRowInComponent" is called, assuming that number of rows is always 0